# Integration over region given by inequality

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Sometimes we need to integrate over some bounded region given by inequality/inequalities. Consider the following simplest example of area of an ellipse (LaTeX code):

$\int_S dx dy$, where $S = \{ x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 \leq 1\}$.

Is it possible to do this directly in Mathematica? If possible, how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!. Please, post the _Mathematica_ code you tried.

Comment: Check the *> Scope > Integrals over Regions* part of the `Integrate` documentation for some examples

Comment: related: [NIntegrating within an Ellipsoid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2833/nintegrating-within-an-ellipsoid) and [Check homework integration in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6633/57)

Comment: @ssch Oh, I didn't realize there is a tutorial on this topic. I only searched the examples in vain. Thanks.

Comment: I think this question puts the issue more clearly and concisely than the referenced question that it allegedly duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicitly:

```
Integrate[Boole[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 <= 1], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
          Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

Function `Boole` delineates the region; the `Assumptions` option is needed for symbolic `a` and `b` in order to allow Mathematica actually to evaluate the integral; if `a` and `b` are numeric, that option is superfluous.

Comment: If you integrate over the entire plane `Integrate[
Boole[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 <= 1],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]` it will still get evaluated but return a `Piecewise` with conditions on `a` and `b`

Comment: @ssch: Yes, but I was trying to avoid any problems (which don't arise in this particular example) with behavior at infinity. I don't know whether that's a concern in a more general situation: I'd expect the `Boole` expression to prevent problems, but will it always -- what does Mathematica actually do here?