# Integration using Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, webmathematica

Assuming $0<x,y<1$ and $0<v<1$,
consider the function $f(x,y)=1+(1-2x)(1-2y)$. 
How to find the integral $I=\int_{\{xy+xy(1-x)(1-y)\leq v\}} \,f(x,y)\;dx \, dy$ using *Mathematica* or Matlab?

I am trying to show that  $I \leq v$ by this integral for which the integration of $f(x,y)$ over the region $\{ xy+xy(1-x)(1-y) \leq v\}$ is essential.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6633/2079

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_] := 1 + (1 - 2 x) (1 - 2 y)

int[v_] := NIntegrate[Boole[x y + x y (1 - x) (1 - y) <= v] f[x,y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

For example:

```
int[0.5]
```

> 0.763851

```
Plot[{v, int[v]}, {v, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Dashed}, Red}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameLabel -> {"v", ""}]
```

[image]